# Fragment's enter and exit transitions not seen

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-5.0-lollipop, android-transitions

I have a simple activity which holds a FrameLayout to load a fragment. I have set Fragments Enter and Exit Transitions to Slide up from bottom using the Android L's Transition Framework. The Activity's onCreate() has a function which begins a FragmentTransaction to load the fragment up. When my activity starts I can't see any enter/exit transition on the fragment. It just pops up. But, to see whether I implemented Transition framework correctly I used an onClickListener on the FrameLayout and I started the fragmentTransaction on Click. This time after the activity starts and I click the blank FrameLayout, the fragment slides up from bottom with the set Transition. 
But I want this transition on fragment to happen as the activity is created. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To animate the process of enter and exit fragment animation, you will use the `Fragment Manager` to create a `Fragment Transaction`.

Use the following code :

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit);

SampleFragment sampleFragment = SampleFragment.newInstance();

ft.replace(R.id.details_fragment_container, newFragment, "sampleFragment");

// Start the animated transition.
ft.commit();
```

Now, in the `anim` folder you will create two xml files one for enter animation and another for exit animation. You will use the `objectAnimator` tag. Example of enter animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set>
  <objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:propertyName="x" 
    android:valueType="floatType"
    android:valueFrom="-1280"
    android:valueTo="0" 
    android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```

Comment: Thank You, Is it not possible to use Lollipop's `fragment.setEnterTransition()` and `fragment.setExitTransition()` to achieve the same?